# How can I say: “as your friend I would …”

Tags: translation, word-usage

I know the usage of the word *als*:

> Als ich Kind war, hatte ich viele Hobbys.

But I don’t know if I can use this word as the translation for the word *as*:

> Als Ihr Kunde bin ich zufrieden mit Ihrem Service.
>
> As your customer, I’m satisfied with your service.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: No comma after “als Ihr Kunde”, though. And it is either “als Ihr Kunde” (male) or “als Ihre Kundin” (female).

Comment: I corrected some spelling mistakes. However, I am not sure, which is correct: "Als ich Kind war" or "Als ich ein Kind war". And I am not sure about the capital letter of "Ihr Kunde".

Comment: @Iris, "Kind" and "ein Keind" are both possible. https://youtu.be/vc0090gH4Qc

Comment: Or: Als Kind hatte ich viele Hobbies.

Answer (score 5):

It would be absolutely acceptable and correct to use

> als dein Freund/als deine Freundin...

For example when beginning a sentence with some advice or *what I would do if I were in your shoes*.

However, another phrase you may use in that context would be

> Also, wenn ich du wäre...

Meaning

> If I were you...